Typescript Exclude built in type not work in enum case
I am confused about the usage of enums in the following code:
enum IdEnum {
  A = "aa",
  B = "bb",
  C = "cc",
  D = "dd",
}
type IdValues = `${IdEnum}`; //  "aa" | "bb" | "cc" | "dd"
type IdWithoutA = Exclude<IdValues, IdEnum.A>; // "aa" | "bb" | "cc" | "dd", why?

If I want to exclude "aa" for the type IdWithoutA, I have to use type IdWithoutA = Exclude<IdValues, 'aa'>. I am confused about this behavior. Why am I unable to use IdEnum.A here? Could anyone please help?

• There's nothing obviously "frontend" about this question. Is that a mistaken tag? Can we remove it? If not, why not? • Because "aa" is a supertype of IdEnum.A. Either you should widen IdEnum.A to "aa" via a template literal type, or you need to write a different Exclude-like filter that excludes supertypes instead of subtypes, like this playground link shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write an answer (although the answer already here covers some of this). If not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thank you and i just edit the tags.  Meanwhile, i am confused about this comment Because "aa" is a supertype of IdEnum.A IdEnum.A is not equal to 'aa'?

See this playground link. The type IdEnum.A is not equal to the type "aa" (though the values with those names compare equal at runtime). You can think of IdEnum.A as "aa" with a "tag" that marks it as IdEnum. It's a feature of enums to prevent you from cross-assigning them. Enums are one of the few places in TS where types behave nominally and not just structurally. Does this clear up the confusion yet? If so I'll write an answer unless you think I'm missing something. If not, what is still confusing?

Convert the enum type to a string type first:
type IdWithoutA = Exclude<IdValues, `${IdEnum.A}`>;


Thank you, but why should we convert it to string first.. : ( still could not understand

"aa" is not assignable to the type IdEnum.A, so Exclude doesn't do anything.
